# basic makefile ifeq how to

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am just learning about Makefiles and am having trouble with ifeq.

Version  = GNU Make 3.82

Here is my simple Makefile:

```
CHECK := 0
CHECK2 := 0                                                                                     

check :  
    @echo "Check=${CHECK}"
    @echo "Check2=${CHECK2}"    
ifeq (${CHECK2},${CHECK}) 
    @echo "EQUAL"
else
    @echo "NOT EQUAL"
endif
```

Here is the output:

```
Check=0
Check2=0                                                                                     
NOT EQUAL
```

Why am I not seeing "EQUAL"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makefiles (and make) are extremely white-spaces sensitive. You seem to have a lot of white spaces in definition of `CHECK2` (but not for `CHECK`), so they are not equal.

Comment: That's it!  It works now thanks!  (Man, I spent a lot of time on that)

Comment: Specifically (from the manual) "trailing space characters are not stripped from variable values".

Comment: Thank you Etan.  I guess I should RTFM.  For others having the same issue, the statement from the manual is found in gnu.org make manual > 6.2 the Two Flavors of Variables.  I only read > 6.5 Setting Variables